# ¿Por que luego de importar librerias no puedo acceder a una funcion?

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando una pagina que obtiene informacion de una base de datos y genera unos graficos, para generar dichos graficos debo hacer uso de la libreria chart.js, el porblema es que cuando importo esta libreria en mi archivo .js, me 'bloquea' una funcion. Asi:

```
import { Chart } from "chart.js";


function diagramaDeBarras(properties, values){
    localStorage.setItem("properties",properties)
    localStorage.setItem("values",values)
    let miCanvas = document.getElementById("miCanvas");
    let chart = new Chart(miCanvas,{
        type:'bar',
        data:{
            labels: properties, 
            datasets:[{
                label: "Resumen Inventario",
                backgroundColor: "rgb (255,0,0)",
                data:values
                }
                
            ]
        }
    })
}

function ListarDatos(){
    let date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    let datParts = date.split("-");
    let dateToShare = datParts[2]+"/"+datParts[1]+"/"+datParts[0];
    var parametros = {"Fecha":dateToShare};
    $.ajax({
        data:parametros,
        url:'assets/getRegister.php',
        type: 'get',
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (response) { 
            OrganizarDatos(response);
        }
     });
}
```

La funcion a la que no puedo acceder es ListarDatos(), no puedo llamarla con onclick desde un button, cosa que antes de hacer el import, si podia hacer.

dentro de ese mismo archivo, tengo la funcion para graficar el diagrama que necesito y sin la libreria, esta no funciona.

Cabe resaltar que la libreria la importe por la terminal utilizando el comando 'npm i chart.js' por lo que se añadieron a mi carpeta de trabajo, dos archivos .Json y la carpeta node_modules.

Comment: Como mantra: el código se comparte como texto. Nadie te va a responder con imágenes pa ponerte a transcribir ;)

Comment: @Alfabravo Corregido :) muchas gracias

Comment: Y ese código dónde está? Un script aparte o entre medio del html? Porque no veo el `onclick`